# How to achieve consistency in divs changing background of other divs?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have two divs, #left and #right. When I hover over #left I would like the content of #right to change, and vice versa. After hover, the content reverts to what it was before hovering.

Currently, hovering over #left changes the background of #right, but the exact same code does not work vice versa.

```css
#left:hover+#right {
  background-image: url('working image url');
}

#right:hover+#left {
  background-image: url('working image url');
}

#left:hover:after,
#right:hover:after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="left">Content</div>
<div id="right">Content</div>
```

Comment: This can't work `#right:hover+#left` since left comes before right and `+` only selects the immediate sibling that comes after

Comment: Is there an alternative way of writing this code that would allow hovering over #right to change the background of #left?